# Запись в файл и чтение

Tags: android, java, файлы

Добрый день. Возможно ли записать данные в файл без перезаписи, то есть с добавлением к уже имеющимся данным? [Прилагаю код](http://pastebin.com/sCk9pdS4)

```
MyText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
// Добавить
void write() {
    try{
        // Читаем
        String line;
        // Открываем буфер
        BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE), "UTF-8"));
        Writer.append(MyText.getText());
            Writer.flush();
            // Закрываем
        Writer.close(); 
        Log.d("WriterFile", "Записано!");
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте флаг `MODE_APPEND` при открытии файла:

```
openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, и правда, работает. Странно то, что просто
MODE_APPEND не дает такого же результата!